# Leaflet infinite vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to reproduce behavior of leaflet's `worldCopyJump()`, but for vertical scrolling: for world map it's when user scrolls up from North Pole, the South Pole is shown. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the default map projection.

By default, Leaflet uses EPSG:3857 AKA "Web Mercator", a type of [cylindrical map projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Cylindrical). In cylindrical map projections, two points (in this case, the geographical north and south poles) **can not be represented in the map at all**.

What you see is a cropped version of this map projection: The map is cut out as approximately ~85°N and ~85°S in order to look square. In reality, the map projection is **infinite in the vertical axis**.

This said:

- Read the [leaflet tutorial on `CRS.Simple`](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html). You can use projections other that the default.
- Read the [documentation for `L.CRS`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#crs). It's important in order for you to...
- Read [Leaflet's source code for CRSs](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/geo/crs/CRS.Earth.js). Pay extra attention to those `wrapLat` and `wrapLng` properties.
- Research on map projections. Is there any wrapping projection that serves your purposes? Can you achieve that with [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet)? If not...
- Write your own custom `L.CRS` with the desired wrapping.